# SPfx gulp-serve command not launching the browser page in local host

Tags: spfx-webparts, testing, gulp

I have created HelloWorld web part from [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) tutorial.

The command `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` and `gulp trust-dev-cert` executed successfully.

After that, I executed `gulp serve` command which shows below screen. More than ten minutes are passed the browser is still not launched.

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how would I be able to test the web part? I am totally new to the SPFX concepts.

Node JS version is: 6.12.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this Mac or windows machine ? can you try running it using admin account ?

Comment: update the package generator using "*npm install -g  @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest*", then try again

Comment: @GautamSheth I am running the PowerShell (in Windows machine) Command using the Admin account only.